# How to get ComboBox.SelectedItem to bind when SelectedIndex is changed?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, combobox

In my application, I will need to update a certain image when the selection of my `combobox` changes. Currently I do this by capturing the `SelectedIndexChanged` event and update the image there.

I have been trying another approach to do it, namely, using `Binding` in order to simplify my code, but it doesn't work.

Because the binding of `ComboBox.SelectedItem` to a certain property only applies *after* the `ComboBox` loses focus or when another control gains focus-- not when or before the `SelectedIndexChanged` event is fired.

How to get the binding to apply immediately when the `SelectedItem` or the `SelectedIndex` is changed?

This is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private readonly Person person;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        person = new Person()
        {
            Name = "joe",
            Race = Race.Indian
        };



        textBox1.DataBindings.Clear();
        textBox1.DataBindings.Add(nameof(textBox1.Text), person, nameof(person.Name));

        comboBox1.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Race));
        comboBox1.DataBindings.Clear();
        comboBox1.DataBindings.Add(nameof(comboBox1.SelectedItem), person, nameof(person.Race));
        comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;

    }

    private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //when selected index is changed, the data is lagging behind the selected item. 
       //eg: SelectedItem is already Chinese, but person.Race is still Indian
        MessageBox.Show($"data {person.Race}, selected item {comboBox1.SelectedItem}"); 
    }

    private int count = 0;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        person.Race =(Race)(((int)person.Race + 1) % Enum.GetValues(typeof(Race)).Length);
        person.Name = person.Name + $"{count++}";
    }
}

public enum Race
{
    Indian,
    Chinese,
    Causacian,
    Arabian,
    Jewish,
    SouthINdian,
}
public class Person: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Race _race;
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;

        }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Name)));
        }
    }
    public Race Race
    {
        get
        {
            return _race;
        }
        set
        {
            _race = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs (nameof(Race)));

        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you trying to avoid using the `SelectedIndexChanged` event?

Comment: @Laslos, I just prefer binding so that all my code looks consistent --  I do binding for `TextBox`, so why not for `ComboBox` as well?

Comment: OK, i use `SelectedIndexChanged` frequently so I was wondering if there was some drawback I was unaware of.

Comment: @Laslos , no drawback that I am aware of. Just that you need more lines of code to accomplish essentially the same thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve the problem, you can bind to `SelectedValue` property:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Race)).Cast<Race>()
    .Select(x => new { Value = x, Display = x.ToString() })
    .ToList();
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Display";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
comboBox1.DataBindings.Add(nameof(comboBox1.SelectedValue), person, nameof(person.Race),
    true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

Comment: Bind to `combobox1.SelectedValue`, although does update the data source immediately, nonetheless doesn't update from data source to `combobox` _at all_. You can see this by clicking on `button1` in my original example.

Comment: Also, on your second suggestion to extend `ComboBox` class and add a `SelectedItemChanged ` event, it doesn't work

Comment: Not sure where you get the impression that `ComboBox `developers forgot to implement the event for `OnSelectedItemChanged`, I see [the source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ComboBox.cs,2626) and it does look like they did implement the event properly.

Comment: For now, I removed the descriptions about `SelectedItem` and just kept the `SelectedValue` solution. But I'll check `SelectedItem` again.

Comment: About the event, they have added all implementations, but forget to add the event `public event EventHandler SelectedItemChanged`. Without having that, you can not subscribe to the event.

Comment: Your latest example still not working; the update from data to UI doesn't work, and even from UI to data is also not working

Comment: @Graviton Maybe your test environment is not clean. I tested it again and it works as expected. Two-way data binding is working, by click on the button, UI updated immediately, by change the Combobox in UI, data updated immediately.

Comment: Ah, I binded to the wrong property, that's why it didn't work. Now it works now

Comment: Good to hear that was helpful!